# winddk: __iob_func redefinition

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

I am trying to link a user space library into a windows kernel driver. It has a reference to __iob_func which is part of "libcmt.lib" (user space library). 
I don't have access to this function in winddk. So, I am planning to define a stub for __iob_func which will try to emulate the same functionality as done in user space library.

Does anyone know what __iob_func do? I found the declaration of the function in the header files. But I am not sure what functionality it exactly does.

Comment: I think iob_func returns a file descriptor to which things will be returned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`__iob_func()` returns a pointer to the array of `FILE` descriptors that holds `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` and any `FILE` objects opened through the C runtime library.  See the MSVC runtime library source `_file.c`.

If your user-space library code actually tries to do much with the C runtime, you'll probably run into a lot of headaches linking it into your kernel driver.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I could compile the driver with an empty stub defined for __iob_func. Library does use functions like strcpy, memcpy. But they are also part of winddk. So, I am good with that. Can you suggest a way to handle __iob_func(). Is there any function in winddk to which I can direct calls to __iob_func().

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be anything corresponding to `__iob_func()` in the DDK/kernel since the kernel doesn't use C runtime `FILE` objects.  I'd just try returning `NULL` from your stub and see if anything crashes from trying to actually use it.  If something does use it, there would need to be some analysis done for how to resolve that problem.

Comment: Thanks. By returning a NULL pointer, things seem to work. I do understand that there can be some hidden problem which will surface once I touch part of the code which uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Disassemble the following c code. cl /Fa mycode.c

```
fflush (stdin) ;
fflush (stdout) ;
fflush (stderr) ;
```

This is basically what the assembly file output with the /Fa switch on the c file will look like:

```
call ___iob_func  ; invoke the c function __iob_func
push eax          ; invoke fflush with 1 parameter   
call _fflush
add esp, 04h      ; realign the stack adding 4 bytes to 
                  ; the stack pointer (esp).
```

So, apparently the __iob_func returns a pointer to array or structure of input output buffer information; hence the *iob* acronym followed by *func* (__iob_func). i stands for input, o for output, b for buffer, etc......

That's just the fflush(stdin) function. fflush(stdout) repeats the same 4 lines with the only difference for stdout in the second line: 
    push eax + 020h
So, apparently each array member is composed of 32 bytes or 8 double words.

For stderr the assembler posted push eax + 040h or eax + 64 bytes

Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN) doesn't document the __iob_func function. But it's declaration probably would be something like the following: lpReturn __iob_func ( void )

32 bit assembly usually returns the value of a function in the eax register. And when the input parameter value of a function is described as an addition to a register (e.g. eax + 020h), it usually means that its referring to a structure or array of some type. So eax would be the starting address of the structure or array. And eax + 020h would be a location in that structure where information for stdout begins. eax + 040h would be the location where stderr begins.

So basically, if you want to use the __iob_func in your c program, you would have to prototype the function, and then perhaps create your own personal lib

mylib.def

LIBRARY    msvcrt.dll

EXPORTS
    __iob_func

And then run lib on that file.
LIB /def:mylib.def /machine:x86

That should create a 32 bit library called mylib.lib which you can use to link into your program.